# Looking for Real Stories of Web Service Security Breaches

Tags: security

I'm a full time software developer, but on the side I'm teaching a university course on web services.  I'm going over security right now and was wondering if any of you all have had any security breaches that you could tell about (details obscured as needed) that I could share with my students.  Real life stories are a lot more meaningful than made up scenarios...

Comment: Probably change to community wiki

Comment: This is a great question.  Web Service security is something you do as a default best practice, though I've never heard of an incident where security was breached or more importantly where a lax security strategy was compromised making a case for a more complex security strategy.

Comment: "Probably change to community wiki."  Good idea.  Done.

Comment: Rich, absolutely agree.  I illustrated this in class by talking about the dangers of iguana bites--yes, truely dangerous, but very unlikely to happen.  Kind of puts it in context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a story from me:

I once was customer of an online audiobook store. Beside authenticating myself with username and password, I also needed my browser to accept cookies. This wasn’t unusual. The cookie is probably needed for storing the session ID.

But I got confused since the session ID was also transmitted in the URL and I didn’t saw a reason for why there was a need for cookies. So I took a look into my cookie jar to see what oh so important information have to be stored in cookies.

Beside a cookie for the session ID there was another cookie named `customer_id` that obviously was designated to identify me by my customer number. I thought: “*Come on, no one can be this stupid!*” I altered the value for fun by changing one digit of the number (e.g. from 12345 to 12346) to see what happens.

Now guess what: I now was logged in as a different user *without* any further request for authentication just by changing the cookie! The `customer_id` cookie value was abviously not just for identification (*Who am I?*) but also for authentication (*Am I really the one who I pretend to be?*)!

The moral of this story: **[Always separate identification from authentication.](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc512578.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you had in mind, as there was no information compromised, but it still *very much* a web security issue.

http://www.crime-research.org/library/grcdos.pdf

That is the classic story of how internet security guru, Steve Gibson's, site was attacked by a botnet. It is a very interesting story and would certainly keep the class engaged. I know this story got me more interested in web security.

I could not find the original post of that pdf on Steve Gibson's site (grc.com), but I had a copy on my computer and was able to search for it and found it at the given location.

I also recommend going to grc.com and listening to the "Security Now!" podcasts:

http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm

You will almost surely hear some stories in some of those podcasts.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The European Identity Conference (EIC 2009) in Munich will be featuring a case study on SOA security that will have the information you seek.